# How to enable dates for specific blog post only in blogger?

Tags: blogger, dates

I am trying to enable dates for selective blog posts i.e. for which information date information is relevant, but want to disable them for evergreen posts.

Blogger doesn't provide an out-of-box option to enable or disable date for a particular post (maybe I am not aware).

How can we do that using Blogger platform?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is hide the date using CSS. In the posts that you don't want to show the date on, add the following code in the HTML tab of the post editor:

```
<style>
h2.date-header {
  display: none !important;
  }
</style>
```

If you don't want to show the date on any posts, then you can add the above to the footer.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn them off for all posts, and then manually add a date to the post content (eg on the first line) if it relevant.

(I guess this will be best if most of your posts are evergreen or deciduous, and only a few are date-specific.)